# SELECT items that has one or more specific TAGS

Tags: mysql

I have three database tables.

One with items, one with tags and one with items_has_tags.

Tags

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='';
INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'tag one'),
(2, 'tag two'),
(3, 'tag three'),
(4, 'tag four'),
(5, 'tag five');
```

Items

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) COMMENT='';
INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'first item'),
(2, 'second item'),
(3, 'third item'),
(4, 'fourth item');
```

Item has tag

```
CREATE TABLE `item_has_tag` (
  `item_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL,
) COMMENT='';

INSERT INTO `item_has_tag` (`item_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 1),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 2),
(3, 3),
(3, 4),
(1, 2),
(4, 3),
(4, 4),
(4, 5);
```

I want to only select items that have all the specific tags, such as the items that item_has_tag.tag_id = 1 AND item_has_tag.tag_id = 2 AND item_has_tag.tag_id = 3 for example.

*edit*

The amount of specific tags varies from 1 to 4-5.

*edit*
It is the items list that needs to be returned.

Would you like to help me?

Comment: Don't you _really_ want to start with `tags.name IN ('dog', cat', bird')`?

Comment: Yhea, you have a point, but in this case, the situation is that we have the id's already, the SQL code above is just dummy examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a specific tags list you can simply calculate the amount of tags from this list attached to each item using

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(tag_id IN (specific_tags_list))
FROM item_has_tag
GROUP BY item_id
```

To obtain the list of items which have all of the tags in tags list you must compare calculated SUM() with the amount of tags in the list:

```
SELECT item_id
FROM item_has_tag
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING amount_of_tags_in_list = SUM(tag_id IN (specific_tags_list))
```

> items that item_has_tag.tag_id = 1 AND item_has_tag.tag_id = 2 AND item_has_tag.tag_id = 3 for example

For this case the query will be

```
SELECT item_id
FROM item_has_tag
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING 3 = SUM(tag_id IN (1,2,3))
```

**PS.** The fields pair (item_id, tag_id) must be defined as unique by index (in any order, maybe primary) in the table `item_has_tag` structure.

---

**UPDATE**

---

> Your code works very well but I get into trouble when I try to get the
>   result from the items list SELECT items.* FROM items, item_has_tag
>   GROUP BY item_has_tag.item_id HAVING 3 = SUM(item_has_tag.tag_id IN
>   (1,2,3)) Error "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause"

Variant 1:

```
SELECT items.*
FROM items, ( SELECT item_id
              FROM item_has_tag
              GROUP BY item_id
              HAVING 3 = SUM(tag_id IN (1,2,3))
            ) subquery
WHERE items.id = subquery.item_id
```

Variant 2:

```
SELECT items.name /* , another fields */
FROM items, item_has_tag
WHERE items.id = item_has_tag.item_id
GROUP BY items.name /* , another fields */
HAVING 3 = SUM(item_has_tag.item_id IN (1,2,3))
```

Variant 3: disable session `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL Mode (not recommended).

**PS.** Variants 1 and 2 can be freely converted to JOIN form.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can work with that, but I need items and not the item_id

Comment: @PaRoxUs Add `items` table into FROM section and obtain the field which you need.

Comment: Could this approach with a join statement too?

Comment: @PaRoxUs You may add it with JOIN or using cartesian - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your code works very well but I get into trouble when I try to get the result from the items list

SELECT items.*
FROM items, item_has_tag
GROUP BY item_has_tag.item_id
HAVING 3 = SUM(item_has_tag.tag_id IN (1,2,3))

Error "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause"

Comment: I also get into the same trouble when trying it with a JOIN

Comment: You are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, you're simply looking for the OR operator

```
SELECT item_id
FROM item_has_tag
WHERE tag_id = 1 OR tag_id = 2 OR ...
```

Answer (score 0):

For an explicit labels show you can just figure the measure of labels from this rundown appended to every thing utilizing

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(tag_id IN (specific_tags_list)) 
FROM item_has_tag 
Gathering BY item_id
```

To get the rundown of things which have the majority of the labels in labels show you should think about determined Aggregate() with the measure of labels in the rundown:

```
SELECT item_id 
FROM item_has_tag 
Gathering BY item_id 
HAVING amount_of_tags_in_list = SUM(tag_id IN (specific_tags_list))
```

Comment: `Gathering BY` ...?